# Semantic tag to represent a View container

Tags: html, backbone.js, semantic-markup

I was wondering if I should use any html specific tag to mark a backbone view. I'm working on a big code database that is a sea of divs.

I would like to add some meaning to the html tags that are used to render Backbone Views so is easier to debug.

I was planning to add some class naming convention but there is no budget for it :P.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on what your View does. Using Backbone to render your markup shouldn't change how you structure your HTML. How would you write it statically? Follow that as your guideline for creating your View.